# jQuery .preventDefault();

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have a 2 jQuery scripts- one before I added .preventDefault, and a copy of the same script after I added the .preventDefault. jQuery works in the initial, but not after I add .preventDefault()

Initial script that works

```
$(window).load(function(){  
       $(document).ready(function(){  
         $("span[id$='_ff5_1']").each(function() { //returns a collection of elements that must be iterated through using each
            if ($(this).text() == "Yes") { //test value returned from non-input field
                clearID(); 
                $("tr.anon").hide(); 
            } else {
                $("tr.anon").show();
            }   
         });
         if ($("select[title='action']").val() == "") {   
           $("tr.actDet").hide();      
         }
         $("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function() {          
           if ($(this).val() === "I don\'t know") {             
             alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");         
           } // close if    
            $("select[title='action']").change(function(){         
               $(".actDet").toggle($(this).val()!= "");     
            }); // close action.change
        });//close select.focusout
       }); // close doc.ready 
    }); // close window.load
```

Script that does not work...

```
$(window).load(function(){  
   $(document).ready(function(){  
     $("span[id$='_ff5_1']").each(function() { //returns a collection of elements that must be iterated through using each
        if ($(this).text() == "Yes") { //test value returned from non-input field
            clearID(); 
            $("tr.anon").hide(); 
        } else {
            $("tr.anon").show();
        }   
     });
     if ($("select[title='action']").val() == "") {   
       $("tr.actDet").hide();      
     }
     $("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function() {          
       if ($(this).val() !== "I don\'t know") {
         $(this).preventDefault();
       } else {             
         alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");         
       } // close if    
        $("select[title='action']").change(function(){         
           $(".actDet").toggle($(this).val()!= "");     
        }); // close action.change
    });//close select.focusout-- close edit record stuff
   }); // close doc.ready 
}); // close window.load
```

The only change I made is the initial if statement becomes an if/else that calls .preventDefault(). The first script works great, but the second script fails. Why? I'm calling the .preventDefault() method if the value of the organizationalElement is idk on an existing record.

@Andrew: To clarify on your edit... Should I revise my script to: 
...

```
   if ($(this).val() !== "I don\'t know") {
     $(this).click( function(e) { e.preventDefault(); } );
   } else {             
     alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");         
   } // close if
```

...
b/c I noted taht it will work correctly if I change $(this).preventDefault(); to e.preventDefault();

Are you perhaps trying to show how to write it if I wish to attach the method to the $(this) object as I'd originally written it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to call `preventDefault` on the event object, not `this`

```
$("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function(e) {          
   if ($(this).val() !== "I don\'t know") {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

---

Just for completeness, note that `preventDefault` prevents the *default action* of this element—navigating the page to the value of the href attribute for an anchor, for example  (I'm not sure what the default action is for a select's focusout, or if there even is one). `preventDefault` **does not** prevent bubbling.

If you happen to care about bubbling—and I'm not saying that you necessarily should—returning false from a jQuery event handler will both prevent the default action, and also prevent bubbling.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I am aware that preventDefault does not stop the event from bubbling, however I am not sure that I do not want the bubbling.  Is that perhaps what stopped the entire jQuery script from working?

Comment: @jg100309 - no, your original problem was that you were calling preventDefault on this, instead of the event object.  Pass the event object to your handler, and call preventDefault on *it*, like in my answer

Comment: *Side Note: You don't have to escape the `'` character if it's between two `"`s.*

Answer (score 8):

The `preventDefault()` function is associated with the event.  What you should be calling is:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

**edit** to clarify based on your comment, you need to add `e` as a variable in the function call:

```
$('selector').click( function(e) { e.preventDefault(); } );
```

You can read more about in on the [jQuery preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) page.

Comment: Okay, so it will ALWAYS be e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 5):

The `preventDefault` method should be applied to the event object, not to the DOM object as you're doing it.

Your code should be:

```
$("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function(e) {          
       if ($(this).val() !== "I don\'t know") {
         e.preventDefault();
       } else {             
         alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");         
       } // close if    
        $("select[title='action']").change(function(){         
           $(".actDet").toggle($(this).val()!= "");     
        }); // close action.change
    });//close select.focusout-- close edit record stuff
```

Let me know if that helps!